# LWC Spinner not showing overlay in community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, digital-experience

I am developing a LWC component and embedded in community page. Inorder to show the loading I am using like this

```
   <template if:true={isLoading}>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
            </lightning-spinner>
    </template>
```

When I run the component inside salesforce org spinner is showing properly with overlay but in community only spinner is showing and not showing any overlay.

### In community

[image]

### In Salesforce Org

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?